# Joining 2 #temp tables with data from different servers SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, temp-tables

I need to join data from some tables that are located on different servers. I do not have admin rights on the servers so I can't create linked servers which is the immediate response every time someone asks about this. I thought I would try creating a couple of temp tables and then joining those, but while I was able to create the #temp tables successfully and used some WHERE clauses to reduce the amount of data in the tables which is a bonus, I can't figure out how to join the two.  I am using SQL Server Management Studio and it seems like a given SQL query is unable to "see" both temporary tables at once.  Are the temporary tables still stored on the servers that the data is collected from?  I was under the impression that they were all stored in some temp database that I could access all at once.

First I did

```
SELECT ID 
      ,A
      ,B
      ,C
INTO ##Temp1 
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Table1]
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
```

Then in a different window I did

```
SELECT A_ID
    ,Q
    ,R
INTO ##Temp2  
FROM [DB2].[dbo].[Table2]
```

But in my attemp to join the two

```
SELECT A_ID 
    ,Q 
    ,R 
    ,A
    ,B
    ,C   
FROM ##Temp2 AS TableA
LEFT JOIN ##Temp1 as TableB
ON TableA.A_ID = TableB.ID
```

I got the error

```
Invalid object name '##Temp1'.
```

This is my first time attempting something like this and I feel like I'm missing something quite simple here but I was unable to find anything in all my searches.  :/

Comment: This question is missing a lot of detail, likely as a result of not quite knowing what you really need. You mention multiple servers. Are these two different sql server instances (either different machines or named instances)? If so, creating a temp table isn't going to allow you to read data from other servers. That is what link servers are for. The global temp tables you defined are global to the current instance, not some mythical global to your network or something.

Comment: Yes they are different instances.  I thought there could be a way to create a temp table that was global to my network as you put it but alas I see that it cannot be done.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least five options are here, and all of them are not available for a 'normal' user:

1. Create a linked server (you don't need sysadmin permission, you need just 'ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER' permission). But this server should be created just once, so your db admyn can do it for you.

or

2. Export the data to a flat file and import on target server (it can be automated)

or

3. Create an empty DB, copy data, make a backup, restore a backup on target server - can be automated as well  (here you need certain permissions to create a db, make backups/restore, but sysadmin permissions are not necessary)

or

4. Replication

or

5. SSIS

...

If you can create two identical tables on two servers, you can use CMS (Central Management Server) to run the query simultaneously on two servers. Merged results may be inserted to some table and then processed.